# How to Implement Private Route with JWT Token in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, express-jwt, jwt

I'm setting a Dashboard for Authenticated User only. How can I set my frontend to access the Private Route with jwt from backend?

This is the backend process of signin

```
const knex = require('../../../../database');
const path = require('path');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function getUser(email, password) {
  return knex('admin_account')
    .select('email')
    .where({
      email,
      password
    }).first();
}

// app/models/user.js
const signin = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(400)
        .json({
          success: false,
          data: {
            error: "Email and password cannot be empty"
          },
        });
    }
    const result = await getUser(email, password)
    if (!result) {
      return res.status(404)
        .json({
          success: false,
          data: {
            error: "User tidak ditemukan, masukan Email dan Password-mu dengan benar"
          },
        });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: jwt.sign({
        role: 'admin',
        email
      }, process.env.SECRET)
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error({
      error: error.message
    });
    return res.status(400)
      .json({
        success: false,
        data: {
          error: JSON.stringify(error.message)
        },
      });
  }
}
module.exports = signin
```

And this is the Frontend of Login and App

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  state = initialState

  handleSubmit = input => {
    input.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();

    if (this.formisValid(this.state)) {
      this.setState({ errors: [], loading: true });
      formData.set('email', this.state.email)
      formData.set('password', this.state.password)

      axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: config.endpoint + '/api/v1/admin',
        data: formData,
        config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
      })
      .then( response => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.error) {
          this.setState({ 
            initialState,
            submit: true
          });
          this.setState({ loading: false});
          console.log('User Login', response)
          this.props.history.push('/admin/dashboard');
        }


      }).catch((errors) => {
        // ? Show to user that request is failed
        this.setState({ errors: [errors] })
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        console.log('User not found, login failed', errors)
      });
    }
  };

  handleInputError = (errors, inputName) => {
      ...
  };

  render() {
    ...

    return (
        ...
        );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          {/*This is the function to Route to Page (via switch)*/}
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/login/admin" component={Login} />
            ...
            <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

The Signin Process runs smoothly, but i'm stuck with how to keep the token and make the Route Private with jwt

Much appreciate my friend, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question 100%. If I understand correctly, you try to prevent some users from accessing a certain location if it does not have a token (is disconnected).

In my client interface, I use context to manage token and share it between component.

`App.js` will look like this.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <TokenProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <RouteComponent />
      </div>
    </TokenProvider>
  )
};

const RouteComponent = () => {
  const { token } = useContext(TokenContext);

  return (
    <>
      {token ? (
        <Switch>
          ...Private routes
        </Switch>
      ) : (
        <Switch>
          ...Public routes
        </Switch>
      )}
   </>
  )
};
```

To be sure user will not access unvailable location, you set redirection to login page as example.

I hope it can help you and i'm sorry if I made mistake.

NB: This is based on my experience, I don't say that a good way to do that but in my case it resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What @CedFon answered is correct, you can validate the token (and its expiry date ideally) to be able to change routes with React Router.

What I believe is missing from the answer, is how to store the JWT. It can be stored in your cookies, set by the frontend. This will ensure if the user refreshes the page, the token will still be accessible.